# Silverlight DomainDataSource and FilterDescriptors (Entire query loaded from server THEN filtered in client?)

Tags: silverlight, filter, descriptor, domaindatasource

I need to know if DomainDataSource with filterdescriptors added will first load ALL the data from the client and then filter on the client, or do the filter descriptors cause the domaindatasource to create a query with filter added on (.Where(e=>..)) which is then loaded from the server.

In other words: Is there a difference between these two:

```
<riaControls:DomainDataSource AutoLoad="True" d:DesignData="{d:DesignInstance my1:NursingHomeDetail, CreateList=true}" Height="0" LoadedData="nursingHomeSummaryDomainDataSource_LoadedData" Name="nursingHomeDomainDataSourceByPin" QueryName="GetNursingHomeQuery" >
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
        <my:NursingHomeContext />
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.DomainContext>
    <riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
        <riaControls:Parameter ParameterName="pin" Value="{Binding ElementName=pinComboBox, Path=SelectedValue}" />
    </riaControls:DomainDataSource.QueryParameters>
</riaControls:DomainDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

It happens server-side. The filters change the DomainDataSource query client side, which is serialized to server-side for execution.